# /include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:111: boost::mutex::~mutex(): Assertion `!res' failed

Tags: camera, sensors

on Ubuntu 16.04, I compiled the spinnaker SDK src/Acquisition/make, I got the "Acquisition" under bin/
When I run it, I got the error:
Number of cameras detected: 1

Running example for camera 0...

*** DEVICE INFORMATION ***

DeviceID: 18073382
DeviceSerialNumber: 18073382
DeviceVendorName: Point Grey Research
DeviceModelName: Grasshopper3 GS3-U3-32S4M
DeviceType: U3V
DeviceDisplayName: Point Grey Research
DeviceAccessStatus: OpenReadWrite
DeviceVersion: FW:v2.25.3.00 FPGA:v2.02
DeviceDriverVersion: none : 0.0.0.0
DeviceUserID: 
DeviceIsUpdater: 0
DeviceInstanceId: 0113C726
DeviceLocation: 
DeviceCurrentSpeed: HighSpeed
GUIXMLLocation: Device
GUIXMLPath: Input.xml
GenICamXMLLocation: Device
GenICamXMLPath: 
DeviceU3VProtocol: 1

*** IMAGE ACQUISITION ***

Acquisition mode set to continuous...
Unable to begin image acquisition. Aborting with error -1010...

Camera 0 example complete...

Done! Press Enter to exit...

Acquisition_C: /softwarelib/Boost/boost_1_60_0/GCC_5_3_1/linux_cpp11/release/amd64/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:111: boost::mutex::~mutex(): Assertion `!res' failed

The sample code itself doesn't use mutex at all.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to insufficient usbfs memory allocation. Please refer to section 3 of the spinnaker readme as follows for info on how to increase the value to 1000:

===============================================================================

## 3. USB RELATED NOTES

On Linux systems, the USB-FS memory is restricted to 16 MB or less by default. To
increase this limit to make use of the imaging hardware's full capabilities, a
minor change needs to be made to the system.

To PERMANENTLY modify the USB-FS memory:

```
1. Open the /etc/default/grub file in any text editor. Find and replace:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

with this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.usbfs_memory_mb=1000"

2. Update grub with these settings:
$ sudo update-grub

3. Reboot and test a USB 3.1 camera.
```

If this method fails to set the memory limit, to TEMPORARILY modify the USB-FS
memory until the next reboot, run the following command:
    $ sudo sh -c 'echo 1000 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb'

To confirm that the memory limit has been successfully updated, run the following command:
$ cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb

If using multiple USB3 cameras, the USB-FS memory limit may need to exceed 1000.
More information on these changes can be found at:
https://www.flir.com/support-center/iis/machine-vision/application-note/understanding-usbfs-on-linux